# Bootstrap 4 Table column sizing not responding as expected

Tags: css, html-table, responsive, bootstrap-4, dynamic-columns

Being new to bootstrap and scripting with html/css in general, I am attempting to create a simple html table (one row with three columns). Each column is to be even (taking up one third of the table which it exists inside of. The problem I am encountering is that it appears to be taking up only two-thirds (2/3) of the available space with in the table. I've looked on the internet for solutions, googled, read a several posts/articles on stack and other places, but I've not found a solution and am hoping for help.

[You can see a straight html render of the error here](http://marvel-adventures.com/user/user_userCharsRender.php)

Here is a picture detailing the issue:

[image]

As the example image shows the thin red column is taking up one third of the table space (green bordered table), however that table is not expanding to occupy the full space available to it in the red div. I've looked for through the html render and not found a cause for the issue.

```
<div class="area">
        <section class="wrapper scrollable">
            <div class="main-grid">
                <div class="agile-grids">
                    <!-- blank-page -->
                    <div class="blank">
                        <div class="blank-page">
                            <h1>Session is active</h1>


<table class=" " style="border: 1px solid red;">
    <tbody>
        <tr scope="row" style="border: 1px solid red;">
            <td class="text-center" style="border: 1px solid green;">
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12" style="border: 1px solid red;">
                <div class="card_user-charProfile">
                    <img class=" img-fluid" style="width: 100%;" src="http://localhost/wBase/zUploads/cImg/3bgCard.jpg" alt="Wiccan">

                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card">
                            <p> content goes here</p></div>
                        </div>
                    </div> <!-- end row -->
                </div><!-- end CHARACTER PROFILE OUTER DIV -->
            </td>
        </tr>                               
    </tbody>
</table>
                    </div>
                 </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

Here are the CSS declarations / links

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    <!-- This JS disallows hijacking into someone else's frame...
     if (top.location != self.location){top.location=self.location}
    //-->
</script>

<link href="../__themes/bs4_marvelCSS/bs4_bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="../__themes/bs4_marvelCSS/bs4_dashV3.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../__themes/bs4_marvelCSS/style_sticky-footer-navbar.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../__themes/bs4_marvelCSS/bs4_dashTweaks.css" rel="stylesheet">


<!-- font CSS -->

<!-- roboto -->
<link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100,100italic,300,300italic,400italic,500,500italic,700,700italic,900,900italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!-- lato -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- hammersmith one -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Hammersmith+One" rel="stylesheet">


<!-- __themes/_fonts/font-glyphicons.css  -->
<link href="../__themes/bs4_marvelCSS/font.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../__themes/bs4_marvelCSS/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../__themes/bs4_marvelCSS/font-glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script type="application/x-javascript">addEventListener("load", function() { setTimeout(hideURLbar, 0); }, false); function hideURLbar(){ window.scrollTo(0,1); } </script>

<script>
    $(function () {
    $("#supported").text("Supported/allowed: " + !!screenfull.enabled);
    if (!screenfull.enabled) {
        return false;
    }
    $("#toggle").click(function () {
        screenfull.toggle($("#container")[0]);
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using the table? You can handle that all with the bootstrap grid system. Avoid using table in your project. But I will suggest you to give it a width:

```
td{width:100% !important;}
```

Try doing this it may help you.

Comment: I'm using a table as i could get three columns to work within the contact vs. the grid which I was not able to get to appear in columns.

Comment: If you handle the grid correctly you can do every work that table does...

Comment: That did not work, but I've opted to start the build from scratch again. With that in mind I've attempted to construct the three columns and then place small tables inside each as the data will be populated via a php script and is tabular data which is what tables are for as I understand it. This is going better - i guess i've figured some stuff without realizing it. Thanks for the suggest that lead me to go back to rebuild the construction.

Comment: thanks...Well i will suggest you just avoid using tables that is really a bad practice